# Почему картинки не слушаются границам внешних блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, slider

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему когда я задаю фиксированную ширину контейнеров для картинок, они не знают размеров которых я задал и отображаются в полном размере.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.slider__item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 593px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img class="minimized" src="/img/jpeg/проекты/арка.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img class="minimized" src="/img/jpeg/проекты/кинотеатр.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img class="minimized" src="/img/jpeg/проекты/монумент.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img class="minimized " src="/img/jpeg/проекты/новостройка.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img class="minimized" src="/img/jpeg/проекты/центральный-фонтан.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Может причина в том что я использую Slick slider.
Заранее благодарю)))

Comment: Где здесь фиксированная ширина контейнера?

Comment: я про блок slider__item, задал ширину 593px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите в стилях следующее:

```
.slider__item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Тогда картинка будет занимать 100% от блока в котором размещена, в вашем случае это будет 593 пикселя, **и даже если картинка меньше она будет растягиваться** до 593.

---

**Если вы хотите что бы ваша картинка не растягивалась:** Напишите вместо ``` width``max-width: 100% ```. В таком случае если картинка больше чем ширина вашего блока, то ширина картинки станет равна ширине блока, если ширина картинки меньше ширины блока, то ширина картинки не изменится.

**Если не хотите что бы картинка уменьшалась ниже какого то предела:** напишите вместо `width` свойство: `min-width:` с нужным значением.

Comment: спасибо!!!!! Вот дурак, забыл про такую мелочь. Ты лучший бро)))

Comment: Да не запаривайся) Главное задавать вопросы, потому что за всеми этими мелочами не уследишь, а нервов самому во всем этом разбираться не хватит ни у кого, все на всех уровнях тупят, главное не останавливаться) Удачи! а это мой первый ответ на стековерфлоу